# uploadcare using js to store to s3

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, amazon-s3, uploadcare

I am currently using `uploadcare` with the plan that would work with s3 upload.  I have been reading the `api` documentation of `uploadcare` and searched around how to use `jQuery ajax` to send to my `s3` `bucket`
Somehow I just couldn't find the answer to it.

Anyone able to give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you see the auto-copy option? with it you don't have to use ajax or rest api to get all uploaded files in your bucket.

Comment: @DmitryMukhin auto-copy option doesn't give me the option to change upload directory though.

Comment: look at pattern setting of the "custom storage" with it you can control what "directory" files are copied to.

Answer (score 1):

First off, take a look at this question in their [knowledge base](http://kb.uploadcare.com/article/54-uploading-directly-to-s3).
In summary you can use the javascript [REST API](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/rest/#files-post) to achieve that.

The REST API has the method `POST /files/` which is obviously what you need. And which I linked to above.

Comment: I did read these too and that's why I mentioned I have read the `api` documentation.  Got authentication error and tried to add authentication into header.  in the sample it's using `curl -H "Authorization: Uploadcare.Simple demopublickey:demoprivatekey" \
     "https://api.uploadcare.com/files/?stored=true&limit=10&from=5000&ordering=-size"` which I tried adding into my `ajax` `header` which gives me random errors without a proper message which is why I am totally confused

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Maybe if you can show a snippet of your code, I can see if I can help further along that line

Comment: if your question about proper authentication within JS, please ask this specifically. there's nothing difficult in making Uploadcare REST APIi calls via AJAX, you just have to understand what you need for that.